# Can you tell me about any methods that Rails adds to existing Ruby classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class

Before I ask a question, I like to caution everyone that I am a programming newbie, so please correct me if I ask something ridiculous.

I have been reading about Ruby having open classes, i.e a method can be added. However, I am trying to get a few examples of how Rails might have added to existing Ruby classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I have found that a great example is Time

#### From a rails application

Time.

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.3)
1.9.3p125 :001 > Time.
Display all 252 possibilities? (y or n)
                                           Time.module_exec
Time.__delay__                             Time.mongo_thread_local_accessor
Time.__id__                                Time.name
...

Total = 252
```

---

#### From a plain ruby console (IRB)

```
$ irb
1.9.3p125 :001 > Time.
                                 Time.hash                        Time.private_method_defined?
Time.__id__                      Time.include?                    Time.private_methods
Time.__send__                    Time.included_modules            Time.protected_instance_methods
...

Total = 93
```

Answer (score 2):

Rails has so many core extensions they're in a separate gem – [ActiveSupport](https://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport).

No sense trying to explain everything here, I'll just point you to [the Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html). After you are familiar with them, refer to [the documentation](http://as.rubyonrails.org/) when you need to.

Comment: But is RoR extensions the same as opening up a class like for example String? So, what I am trying to find is not a class that inherits from another class, but an existing one that has been opened up and edited. Again, not sure if I am correct with how I am asking this

Comment: @nikifi Yes this is precisely what you want... example: 5.days.from_now opens the Fixnum class and adds a "days" method to it. (and this is in active support)

Answer (score 2):

I second Matheus. ActiveSupport is a good example. Take a look at some source code files here:

https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext

And, here's a typical and simplistic example which adds useful and somewhat controversial methods on standard Array class in Ruby.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/access.rb

Most Ruby libraries have a directory named 'core_ext', 'ext' or something along this line which includes methods that extend Ruby's core library in a way or another. People always reinvent methods and in a sense, ActiveSupport is the definitive compilation of those.